# SSRS Report expression setup

Tags: ssrs-tablix

I have a dataset with 4 fields (Date,SeccurityName, FiledName, Value). In my dataset query I filter the data to bring only records with a specific value in the filed name(Last Price). Following is a sample of my dataset

```
Date    SecurityName    FiledName   Value
5/5/2016    A           LastPrice   20.01
5/6/2016    A           LastPrice   19.8
5/7/2016    A           LastPrice   19.9
5/5/2016    B           LastPrice   43.1
5/6/2016    B           LastPrice   43.5
5/7/2016    B           LastPrice   43.7
```

In this dataset I have data for each security for each business day for the last 5 years.
In my report I need to show in a table The security name , the last value, the value from a month ago, the value from a year ago and the value from three years ago

```
Security name     LastPrice      1M            1Year               3Years
   A                  20.1       18.8            19.01               16.05
```

I would appreciate if someone can give me the best way to build this format.

Answer (score 0):

I would group your table on the Security Name. This would aggregate all records with the same security name on the same line.

Then for each date/value column, create an **IIF** statement to filter for the date that you want:

```
=MAX(IIF(Fields!Date.Value = Parameters!LastDate.Value, Fields!Value.Value, NOTHING))
```

The Last Month (and other dates) would be similar:

```
=MAX(IIF(Fields!Date.Value = DATEADD("M", -1, Parameters!LastDate.Value), Fields!Value.Value, NOTHING))
```

The MAX is used to aggregate the NOTHINGS with the Values.

I think it would be best to have the Last Date as a parameter (with a default of yesterday?) to make it easier to create the expressions and you would also have the ability to look at past dates if you ever have the need.